# UIDocumentInteractionController no longer generate file icons in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11

I used to use UIDocumentInteractionController to generate a file preview icon.

On iOS 11 however, the `icons` property is always empty even for most used file formats like txt or png.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *c = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
c.URL = file.fileURL;
self.previewImageView.image = [c.icons firstObject];
```

Does iOS 11 provide any other way to generate a icon based on file type? Or do I need to configure any other stuff to make this work?

-- Update --

After present the UIDocumentInteractionController once, all icons for the that type of file will work without presenting anymore, even after reboot the device. However other file formats will still produce empty array.

Comment: Have you tried to `presentPreview` and then ask for `icons`?

Comment: After present it once, all icons for the that type of file will work without presenting anymore, even after reboot the device. However other file formats will still produce empty array. Also although presenting fix it in some degree, user will not want it presented if not interacted.

Comment: This simply means that you were _abusing_ `UIDocumentInteractionController` in a way it wasn't intended, now Apple fixed it and generate and cache icons in a lazy way only when the `UIDocumentInteractionController` must be presented.

Comment: @Shebuka The use case is perfectly sensible: I want to display icons for various documents, allow the user to select one, **then** display it.